# updating document on MongoDB using _id and a date

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using a java application to update documents on MongoDB. The unique key is the "_id", but recently I've been asked to update them checking a date field. I wanted to update dpocuments without having to do a find to know if it already existed, so I used the update option upsert:true, but since I use the date in the filter and this is not part of the documents key, I get the error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: TEST.CLIENT index: _id_ dup key: { : { clientId: \"pippoalsugo\" } }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
```

}

Is there a way to update/insert with only one query in this case?
Here the structure of the document on MongoDB and the query I use to update/insert documents.

**Document:**

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "clientId" : "8"
    },
    "CLIENT" : {
            "CLIENT_DOC" : [
                    {
                            "idDoc" : "ret",
                            "dsTimestamp" : "2018-01-15 10:01:01.000000",
                            "LAST_UPDATE" : ISODate("2018-01-15T10:01:01Z")
                    }
            ],
            "LAST_UPDATE" : ISODate("2019-02-05T16:44:56.733Z"),
            "codType" : "client",
            "dsTimestamp" : "2018-01-17 08:23:01.000000"
    }
```

}

**Query:**

```
db.CLIENT.update({
                    "_id": {
                        "clientId": "8"
                    },
                    "ANAGRAFICA_CLIENTE.LAST_UPDATE": {
                        "$lte": {
                            "$date": 1542672000000
                        }
                    }
                   }, {
                    "$set": {
                        "ANAGRAFICA_CLIENTE.codTipoClienteInput": "CLIENTE RETAIL",
                        "ANAGRAFICA_CLIENTE.dsTimestamp": "2018-11-20 00:00:00.000000",
                        "ANAGRAFICA_CLIENTE.LAST_UPDATE": {
                            "$date": 1542672000000
                        }
                    }
                }, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: By the way, I suggest letting the creator of this data know that they are using two different formats for date-time values, SQL-style (with a SPACE in the middle) and [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format (with a `T` in the middle). I suggest using ISO 8601 throughout. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: Unfortunately they know but they don't care ,and actually have more than just 2 formats. We try every time to make them reason and let them see what would be best but they won't ever listening.